# Ajuda com várias divs em Selenium em Python

Tags: python, string, lista, selenium-webdriver

Amigos, podem me ajudar? Quero fazer web scrap de uma página e retornar todos os 8 textos de um span.text-ellipsis. Eu fiz o seguinte código:

```py
    self.otherPlayers = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.text-ellipsis').text
```

mas como eu transformo em string, eu só consigo retornar um valor. como retornar os outros?

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando [`elements`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector) ao invés de `element`:

```
self.otherPlayers = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.text-ellipsis').text
```